# Twitter PHP reply code not working

Tags: php, twitter

I have been trying to make Twitter reply code using PHP and it didn't work. When I run it it just post it as a tweet without the reply to the tweet id.
in_reply_to_status_id doesn't work when I run the code.

is there any solution?

```
            <form action="<?php echo  $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="do"value="do"></input>
            <input type="text" name="tweetid" placeholder="tweet id"></input>
            <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="message"></input>

            </form>

            <?php


            require_once('twitteroauth.php');
            $connect=mysql_connect ("localhost","___","___");
            mysql_select_db ("___");

            if(isset($connect)){
            $do=$_POST ['do'];
            $message=$_POST ['message'];
            $tweetid=$_POST ['tweetid'];

            $consumerKey = '___';
            $consumerSecret = '___';
            $accessToken= '___';
            $accessTokenSecret= '___';
            if(isset($do)){

            $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken,$accessTokenSecret);
            $tt=$tweet->post('statuses/update', array ('status'=>$message , 'in_reply_to_status_id' =>$tweetid));


            }}

            else {

            print "error";
            }
            mysql_close ();
            ?>
```

Comment: Have you made sure `$tweetid` isn't empty?

Comment: yes, u can try it from here http://vzide.com/includes/reply.php

Comment: This `if(isset($connect)){` that doesn't make any sense. You should be doing something like `if($connect){...}` or `if (!$connect) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: its working and I tried it in other codes, this is not the problem.

Comment: Hm... ok, fair enough. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: it says 
Notice: Undefined index: do in /home/alialnoaman/public_html/includes/reply.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: message in /home/alialnoaman/public_html/includes/reply.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: tweetid in /home/alialnoaman/public_html/includes/reply.php on line 18

Comment: That can be fixed by adding a check to ensure `$_POST` isnt empty before you process anything. - i.e. `if(!empty($_POST)) { /*do stuff*/}` or check the values themselves - `if(isset($_POST['tweetid']) && !empty($_POST['tweetid'])) { /*do stuff*/ }`